# R-- repeating linear regression in a large dataset

Tags: r, regression

I'm an R newbie working with an annual time series dataset (named "timeseries"). The set has one column for year and another 600 columns with the yearly values for different locations ("L1," "L2", etc), e.g. similar to the following:

```
Year    L1     L2     L3    L4
1963   0.63   0.23   1.33  1.41
1964   1.15   0.68   0.21  0.4
1965   1.08   1.06   1.14  0.83
1966   1.69   1.85   1.3   0.76
1967   0.77   0.62   0.44  0.96
```

I'd like to do a linear regression for each site and can use the following for a single site:

```
timeL1<-lm(L1~Year, data=timeseries)
summary(timeL1)
```

But I think there must be a way to automatically repeat this for all the locations. Ideally, I'd like to end up with two vectors of results-- one with the coefficients for all the locations and one with the p-values for all the locations. From some searching, I thought the plyr package might work, but I can't figure it out. I'm still learning the basics of R, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with one line of code:

```
apply(df[-1], 2, function(x) summary(lm(x ~ df$Year))$coef[1,c(1,4)])
                   L1           L2          L3          L4
Estimate -160.0660000 -382.2870000 136.4690000 106.9820000
Pr(>|t|)    0.6069965    0.3886881   0.7340981   0.7030296
```

Comment: Thanks! Possibly a silly follow-up, but what do the numbers in brackets after coef represent?

Comment: This is matrix subsetting (`$coef` is a matrix), selecting the frist row and the first and fourth columns

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `apply` and `lapply` can accomplish this.

```
d <- read.table(text="Year    L1     L2     L3    L4
1963   0.63   0.23   1.33  1.41
1964   1.15   0.68   0.21  0.4
1965   1.08   1.06   1.14  0.83
1966   1.69   1.85   1.3   0.76
1967   0.77   0.62   0.44  0.96", header=TRUE)

year <- d$Year
d <- d[,-1]
models<-apply(d, 2, function(x) lm(x ~ year))
summaries <- lapply(models, summary)
pvals <- lapply(lapply(summaries, coefficients), function(x) x[4])
coefs <- lapply(lapply(summaries, coefficients), function(x) x[1])
```