# Creating a matrix of OLS results

Tags: r, loops, matrix, linear-regression

I have a data set of excess returns for 576 years for 25 asset portfolios(it goes on till 201012 and er25)

```
 date    er1     er2     er3     er4     er5   market-rf
196301  12.77   11.19   9.15    10.71   10.87   4.93
196302  -3.48   -3.72   -0.94   -1.06   2.51   -2.42
196303  4.75    -1.7    -0.34    0.99   2.36    3.06
196304  4.55    1.25     1.8     3.29   2.52    4.49
196305  3.15    1.44     2.51    3.89   7.63    1.77
```

I need to run 25 regressions for the `CAPM` model and I need to arrange the alphas(intercepts), betas(the co-efficient) and the t-statistic of the intercept in a 25x3 matrix form.

Here are my regressions.

```
capm1 <- lm(er1~market.rf, data=ff25)
capm2 <- lm(er2~market.rf, data=ff25)
capm3 <- lm(er3~market.rf, data=ff25) etc until capm25.
```

I can get the results of `coeftest` like this.

```
coeftest(capm1)
```

`t test` of coefficients:

```
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept) -0.395188   0.204474 -1.9327  0.05376 .  
#market.rf    1.434851   0.045032 31.8629  < 2e-16 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Also, I can extract the 3 variables of interest using

```
summary(capm1)$coef[1,1]
summary(capm1)$coef[2,1]
summary(capm1)$coef[1,3]
```

Could anyone please help me in arranging these variables (I will end up getting 25 intercepts, 25 coefficients and 25 t-statistic of intercept) in a matrix or tabular form. 
Also is there any loop code that can be written to run this ols regression as I had to manually run the regression 25 times for each asset.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972652/r-repeating-linear-regression-in-a-large-dataset/28972825#28972825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight forward looping example is like this:

```
# an index matrix to extract to three values of interest
indx <- matrix(c(1,1,
                 2,1,
                 1,3),nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)

# initialize the output matrix to NULL
out <- NULL

# iterate over the 25 variables
for(i in seq(25)) 
    out  <- rbind(out,
                 coeftest(lm(formula(paste0('er',i,'~market.rf')), 
                             data=ff25))[indx])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I tried running the code and it runs perfectly but without the 1 in coeftest(lm(formula(paste0('er',i,'1~market.rf')) as it was showing an error.